# Loading R packages automatically while preserving the portability of my code

Tags: r, package

I previously used `Rprofile.site` to load my favorite packages (e.g. `dplyr`, `tidyr`). However, numerous sources state using `Rprofile.site` for this purpose makes code less portable. My solution has been to run `source('C:/...startup.script.R')` every time I load R. This startup script runs `require()` for my frequently used packages and a custom package of my custom functions. This works, but in order to share my scripts with others I need to share the script of interest, my custom package, and the `startup.script.R` script.

I would like to design my custom package such that it automatically loads my favorite CRAN functions. I could use `Depends: dplyr, tidyr` or `Imports: dplyr, tidyr` in my package `DESCRIPTION` file. Would this violate best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this question on [Software Engineer Stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390963/is-it-reasonable-for-an-r-package-to-import-another-package-just-for-coding-conv), I decided to use `Imports:magrittr` as the smallest and most widely used package that loads all of my custom package dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `packrat` library for this, it has been recommended by Hadley, Wickam. And it keeps the code clean.

Check out this link - [Packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)